# Android skd 33 not showing xml preview

Tags: xml, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

When I open Android Studio the XML preview in my Android Studio is not showing the mobile-like appearance, it's completely blank (white screen), invisible header and footer. I haven't found any solution on Internet. Here is the picture in the link below.

Comment: There is no link. Can you add a your XML code please ?